# Grid view not displaying in Airflow 2.4.2

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, http-status-code-500, airflow-2.x

We've just upgraded from Airflow 2.2.4 to 2.4.2, which we deploy via k8s and Helm, using the base apache-airflow==2.4.2 Docker image with some other Python packages installed with pip. Part of Airflow 2.4.2 upgrade replaces Tree View with Grid View in the web UI. When we go to Grid View, we see the following:
[image]

The marked up output is your generic Airflow error:

> Ooops!
> Something bad has happened.
>
> Airflow is used by many users, and it is very likely that others had
> similar problems and you can easily find a solution to your problem.
>
> Consider following these steps:
>
> - gather the relevant information (detailed logs with errors,
>   reproduction steps, details of your deployment)
> - find similar issues using:
>
>   - GitHub Discussions
>   - GitHub Issues
>   - Stack Overflow
>   - the usual search engine you use on a daily basis
> - if you run Airflow on a Managed Service, consider opening an issue
>   using the service support channels
> - if you tried and have difficulty with diagnosing and fixing the
>   problem yourself, consider creating a bug report.
>   Make sure however, to include all relevant details and results of your investigation so far.
>
> Python version: 3.9.15 Airflow version: 2.4.2 Node:
> {{deprecated by author}}
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Error! > Please contact server admin.

Looking in our web logs only yields the following text:

`[[34m2022-12-15 01:31:52,943[0m] {[34mapp.py:[0m1741} ERROR[0m - Exception on /object/grid_data [GET][0m`

I can't find any other instance online of another Airflow user experiencing this problem, despite searching for hours.

What could be the problem here? It appears to be an internal Airflow UI issue, so *may* be related to our infrastructure or setup perhaps, but I can't see why.

Also of note, some users had trouble with Grid View when the Operators in their DAGs had a parameters named `params`. I can rule this out as a cause, as our DAGs and Operators definitely do not have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was to do with `dbt-snowflake==1.0.0` being installed as well, and it had some sort of Python package constraint conflict with `apache-airflow==2.4.2`. Upgrading `dbt-snowflake` to v1.3.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly did you make the update? Did you run `helm uninstall airflow` and then `helm install apache/airflow`?

Did you check that run migration job succeed or even if it was executed?

Comment: We were using a base Airflow v2.4.2 Docker image provided by Apache, so it wasn't that. Ended up being conflicts with another package we were installing via pip. Thanks for your response though, much appreciated.